# Pluriel de "il y a"

Tags: étymologie, accord, pronoms-impersonnels, presentation

En français on utilise "il y a" tant pour le pluriel que pour le singulier: on dit "il y a des amis chez moi" et non pas "il(s) y ont des amis chez moi". En anglais et italien, par contre, il faut accorder l'expression d'existence avec le nombre (there are some friends, ci sono degli amici), ce qui paraît logique. Je me demande donc l'origine de cette expression en français et la raison de son invariance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En anglais (*there is/are*) et en italien (*c'è/ci sono*), l'expression est construite sur le verbe être et signifie « ici est … ». Il est logique d'accorder le verbe avec son sujet réel qui est l'entité présentée.

En français (*il y a*) et en allemand (*es gibt*, lit. « il donne »), la construction est différente : l'entité présentée est l'objet d'un verbe qui indique en gros que l'on dispose de cette entité. Le sujet du verbe est un pronom impersonnel, qui est invariable. Il n'y a pas lieu d'accorder ce pronom avec l'entité, pas plus que l'on ne dirait « *<s>ils pleuvent des cordes</s> » sous prétexte qu'il pleut plus d'une corde.

Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir) retrace un bref historique de l'expression (section étymologie et histoire, partie D). On utilisait déjà en bas latin *habet* (lit. « il a », le sujet étant implicite) dans le même sens ; il s'agit d'une tournure impersonelle dérivée de la tournure personnelle *habemus* (« nous avons à notre disposition », « nous possédons », « nous tenons en notre pouvoir »). La tournure est passée en ancien français où elle a acquis l'adverbe *y* que l'on peut rapprocher du *there* anglais : *nous tenons là …*.

On trouve quelquefois la tournure personnelle en français, sans l'adverbe *y* (éventuellement avec l'adverbe *là* à la place).

> Nous arrivons devant la cage de l'ours. Vous avez là un magnifique specimen de 350 kg.
>
> Vous avez là un ensemble idéologique qui va déferler à travers le XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. [[Gilbert Durand, *Champs de l'imaginaire*, 1996](http://books.google.fr/books?id=CTte6Z84R6sC&pg=PA91&dq=%22vous+avez+l%C3%A0+un%22&hl=fr)]
>
> J'ai mon frère qui est malade. [TLF]

Comment: Très belle réponse, merci. J'attends encore un peu pour l'accepter mais elle répond en détail à ma question.

Answer (score 1):

D'après le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki), *[y avoir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/y_avoir)* est une locution verbale impersonnelle dont le sujet est toujours *il*.
Par ailleurs, il n'existe pas non plus de féminin (*elle y a* est inconnu en fançais).

Comment: Merci; des idées sur l'origine de cette expression qui n'a pas des analogues en italien ou anglais (je me suis aperçu, entretemps, que "es gibt" en allemand a un comportement similaire, "sie geben" est inconnu).

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo oui, et l'anglais est similaire à l'italien ici, avec l'accord *there is / there are*. A la limite, on pourrait essayer de dresser une cartographie sommaire... ? Ou n'est-ce que chercher à donner un sens à quelque chose d'arbitraire ?