# Il y a une réflexion à faire sur/au sujet de/à propos de ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, prépositions

> [Il y a](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir) une [réflexion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9flexion) à [faire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) **[sur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur)/[au sujet de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sujet/1)/[à propos de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/propos)** l'alimentation... [réflexion]

Il s'agit d'une tournure [*impersonnelle*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7464/3177) avec le verbe avoir, un nom et son complément sous forme d'infinitif. C'est une manière de *présenter* une réflexion dont on traite par la suite et qui évite de faire intervenir l'interlocuteur dans le discours. Par ailleurs l'utilisation de l'infinitif introduit par *à* est, disons, *économique* et appuie le tour *il y a* (si on compare à une subordonnée avec *que/qui*).

Le verbe [réfléchir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chir) comme tel s'[utilise](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chir&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) avec *à* ou *sur*, ou sans aucune préposition ; mais on voit qu'on n'utilise pas la préposition *à* après *réflexion à faire* ici, à moins d'utiliser ces locutions prépositives plutôt que la préposition *sur* pour introduire (le sujet de) cette réflexion.

- Est-ce qu'on considère que l'une des trois est plus adéquate que les
  autres ici ; y a-t-il une nuance de sens ?
- Il n'est [pas clair](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une%20*%20%C3%A0%20faire%2Cune%20r%C3%A9flexion%20%C3%A0%20*%2Cune%20r%C3%A9flexion%20%C3%A0%20faire%20*%2Ca%20une%20*%20%C3%A0%20faire%2Cune%20r%C3%A9flexion%20au%20sujet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)<sup>1</sup> que la phrase présentée soit
  usuelle. Y a-t-il une manière plus usuelle d'exprimer ce qu'on
  cherche à dire ici (présenter une réflexion, l'introduire, avec le tour impersonnel *il y a*) ?

---

<sub>1. Une centaine de résultats au corpus *Google* ; dont un doublon qui revient :  *Il y a une réflexion à faire sur les médifances* (médisances) *qui coururent contre lui* (Pierre Bayle). On introduit ainsi une réflexion de [Plutarque](https://books.google.com/books?id=DBFhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA668&dq=%22une%20r%C3%A9flexion%20%C3%A0%20faire%20sur%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwA2oVChMI5cKs6e7cxwIVCzqSCh05gQXm) dans un dictionnaire du 18<sup>e</sup>...</sub>

Comment: "Il conviendra/convient de réfléchir sur/à/à propos de" ne fait pas intervenir l'interlocuteur et, évitant le passe-partout "faire", me semble bien plus agréable...

Comment: Franco de port, je dirais "Il y a une réflexion à avoir au sujet de" dans un contexte soutenu (mail client par exemple)

Comment: Merci, vos commentaires offrent des perspectives différentes, svp étayez en réponse. // _Il convient_, est-ce plus prescriptif que _il y a_ ? Convient-il de le dire puis de continuer la réflexion dans la proposition qui suit ? // Franco de port ?? S'il y a qqc. de maritime dans l'expression, j'aimerais bien savoir ; plus sérieusement je crois que vous faites référence à un registre particulier ? Je n'ai pas la référence pour comprendre.

Answer (score 3):

À partir des définitions du petit Robert, des nuances peuvent apparaître, moins dans le sens intrinsèque, que sur le point de vue du locuteur ; bien sûr chaque subjectivité peut être sensible à d’autres subtilités.

> Il y a une réflexion à faire *sur* l'alimentation... [réflexion]

**Sur**

- I - Marquant la position « en haut » ou « en dehors »
- II - Avec un complément désignant ce qui sert de base, de fondement (à cause de, en considération de, en raison de)

Inconsciemment, *sur* positionne le regard, l’attention sur le haut, au-dessus, comme si l’on voyait l’alimentation de haut ; en fait l’alimentation est ici le fondement de la réflexion, on ne prend pas le problème de l’alimentation à la base, à sa source, mais à partir de ce que l’on voit.

L’utilisation de *sur* est mal vue des puristes avec *faire* (car on ne fait rien sur l’alimentation, il n’y a aucune action exercée sur l’alimentation), ils préfèrent l’utiliser directement, de façon plus soutenue :

> *La  réflexion* sur  *l’alimentation...  [+ verbe (autre que faire) + réflexion]*

---

> Il y a une réflexion à faire  *au sujet de* l'alimentation... [réflexion]

**Au sujet de**

du latin *subjectum* « ce qui est soumis, subordonné à » (distingué d’*objectum* → objet) , ce sur quoi s’exerce la réflexion ; pour les sens qui nous intéressent ici :

- I - Dans des expressions : (*au sujet de*) qui fournit matière, occasion à (un sentiment, une action)
- II - En logique : Terme considéré comme le départ de l’énoncé que l’on définit d’une manière logique ou formelle...

C’est l’expression exacte qui convient ici : on observe un sujet, on l’analyse, on projette à son sujet… on réfléchit et la réflexion se développe, quel que soit le contexte (philosophique, économique, académique, scientifique, théologique…) l’expression est ajustée.

L’expression est englobante, car ce *sujet* peut être étudié ici avec son environnement : ce qu’il en reçoit et ce qu’il restitue.

---

> Il y a une réflexion à faire *à propos de* l'alimentation... [réflexion]

**À propos de**

Couramment employé en place de *au sujet de*  avec pour synonymes : *concernant, relatif*.

La réflexion risque d’être moins approfondie, car on ne parle pas du sujet alimentation, mais de tout ce qui concerne l’alimentation, ce qui est en relation avec elle, des propos que l’on tient sur son compte.

Quelqu’un peut employer *à propos de* à la place de *au sujet de* et traiter exhaustivement le sujet, mais il semble que l’on parle moins d’alimentation que d’autre chose en relation avec elle, ou qu’on se focalise sur une seule facette de l’alimentation.

Comment: Bonne rentrée ! Au plaisir !