# De, sur, à propos de, au sujet de, is there a rule of thumb to know when to use them when translating "about"?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, prépositions

Is there a rule of thumb on when to use de, sur, à propos de, and, au sujet de, when translating them as "about"?

De can mean "about" like in:

> J'ai parlé de...

(I spoke about)

Sur can mean "about" in:

> Un livre sur...

(A book about)

À propos de:

> Nous parlons à propos de...

(We're talking about)

And

> Un livre au sujet de...

(A book about)

I'm not sure when to use which, and I'm not even sure if all my sentences are correct.

Answer (score 7):

You have similar variety in English. You can certainly say

> a book about cooking
>
> to talk about many things

but you can also say

> a book on cooking
>
> a book of cooking recipes
>
> a book on the subject of cooking
>
> to talk of many things ([of shoes and ships and sealing wax . . .](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html))

The French *sur* and the English *on* are quite direct translations of each other, and this non-literal secondary meaning is similar.

The French *de* has [many meanings](http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=de) (*marquant l'origine, le lieu, la cause, la manière ou le mode d'action, la qualité*), but *of* is one of them, while the English *about* brings to mind a sense of vicinity, of nearness, of maybe a lot of things all related but maybe not actually central to the subject. You have a more detailed discussion [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/il-y-a-une-r%C3%A9flexion-%C3%A0-faire-sur-au-sujet-de-%C3%A0-propos-de?rq=1) about the implicit meanings of *sur*, *à propos de*, *au sujet de* and when to use one or the other. Without any context, I would probably use *sur* for *on*, and *de* or *à propos de* for *about*.

One thing to watch out for is that *de* can take other sub-meanings of *of* or *from* and *by*:

> un livre de gymnastique --> a book about gymnastics
>
> un livre de cuisine  --> a cookbook
>
> un livre de français --> a school book for French class
>
> un livre de valeur --> a book of value
>
> un livre de Victor --> one of Victor's books (a book of Victor's)
>
> un livre de Victor Hugo --> a book by Victor Hugo (but just maybe *belonging to* . . . it's a matter of context and knowing that Victor Hugo is an author)
>
> un livre sur Victor Hugo --> a book about Victor Hugo
>
> un livre (écrit) par Victor Hugo --> a book (written) by Victor Hugo
>
> une livre de beurre --> a pound of butter (which is a problem with *livre* and not with *de*)

*Au sujet de* and *à propos de* can be useful to resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: _livre_ comme unité de mesure est un nom féminin. Le dernier exemple devrait être _**une** livre de beurre_.

Comment: Or better "*deux livres de beurre*" to keep the point.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois Je me suis laissé emporter :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any rule.

Surely "J'ai parlé sur..." or "Nous parlons sur..." is wrong.
Meanwhile, you can say "J'ai parlé au sujet de..." or "Nous parlons au sujet de..."

In this contexts "de", "au sujet de" and "à propos de" can be indistinctly used.